# I have a problem with tuple objects in my code

Tags: python, tuples, attributeerror

I am currently trying to code a PacMan game on IntelliJ using a Python SDK, but I ran into a problem when it came to tuple objects. The error is specifically referencing to this line:

```
for single_name in name.split(','):
```

The error I receive is "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'"

Here's the code that I'm working with:

```
if constructor is None:
    constructor = font_constructor

if not Sysfonts:
    initsysfonts()

gotbold = gotitalic = False
fontname = None
if name:
    for single_name in name.split(','):
        single_name = _simplename(single_name)
        styles = Sysfonts.get(single_name)
        if not styles:
            styles = Sysalias.get(single_name)
        if styles:
            plainname = styles.get((False, False))
            fontname = styles.get((bold, italic))
            if not (fontname or plainname):
                # Neither requested style, nor plain font exists, so
                # return a font with the name requested, but an
                # arbitrary style.
                (style, fontname) = list(styles.items())[0]
                # Attempt to style it as requested. This can't
                # unbold or unitalicize anything, but it can
                # fake bold and/or fake italicize.
                if bold and style[0]:
                    gotbold = True
                if italic and style[1]:
                    gotitalic = True
            elif not fontname:
                fontname = plainname
            elif plainname != fontname:
                gotbold = bold
                gotitalic = italic
        if fontname:
            break

set_bold = set_italic = False
if bold and not gotbold:
    set_bold = True
if italic and not gotitalic:
    set_italic = True

return constructor(fontname, size, set_bold, set_italic)
```

Comment: `split` is a method for `str` objects, not tuples

Comment: Evidently the thing you're trying to split is a tuple, not a string. If it's supposed to be a string, then wherever that thing came from (not included in your question) has a problem.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, `name` is a [tuple](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp) while you're expecting it to be a string you can split. We're missing the code necessary to see when you instantiate it, so we can't know how to help more than that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to access an element of the tuple, you should use square brackets (i.e. `name[0]`) to index into it. `split` is a common function on strings in python

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like your applying split to the tuple rather then the items in the tuple. Without actually seeing the tuple it's a tough call but does this work better?

for single_name in [name.split(',') for name in name]:

Answer (score 0):

@houseofleft has already answered this, but if the list comprehension (fancy for loop) seems new to you, then here is a simpler explanation.

This is the part where the error lies.

```
if name:
    for single_name in name.split(','):
        single_name = _simplename(single_name)
        styles = Sysfonts.get(single_name)
        ...
```

The error is exactly what it says, you cannot use the "split" method with a tuple. Looking at your code, I feel that you are trying to iterate through items in your tuple called "name." For that, I would do this:

```
if name:
    for single_name in name:
        single_name = single_name.split(sep=',')
        single_name = _simplename(single_name)
        styles = Sysfonts.get(single_name)
        ...
```

Just as a code recommendation, I would avoid using the name "name" of the tuple. Maybe use something like "names" since it contains other objects inside of it; this will help you in the long run.